# Power Query filter date from today minus ? days to today

Tags: date, powerquery, date-range, m, date-difference

I'm just learning Power Query and trying to figure out how modify a filter to return data within a dynamic date range. E.g. from `Today - 60 days` to `Today`
Here's the code, any help much appreciated.

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Start] >= Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-60) and [Start] <= DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Start] >= Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),-60) and [Start] <= Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))
```

Comment: Thx ZygD, just what I need, tweaked it to look at a forward date range as well and works a treat. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

You can do that also in UI.

If your column if type date:
[image]

[image]

Then when you look into Advanced Editor (or formula bar) you will see that Power Query has dedicated function for that:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Date.IsInPreviousNDays([Column1], 60))
```